# cordova inappbilling error package.json is invalid

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am developing a cordova based app.

When I am trying to add this plugin I am getting this error

> Error:Invalid package.json

https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling

I followed this

Here is my code

```
cordova plugin add C:/Users/xxxxx/fbapp/plugins/AndroidInAppBilling --variable BILLING_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the steps below to make it work:

- Download the plugin from github and saved the exploded folder (AndroidInAppBilling-master) in C:\ drive
- Navigate to project root directory and execute the following command:

> cordova plugin add C:\AndroidInAppBilling-master --variable BILLING_KEY="TEST_BILLING_KEY"

In your case it would have thrown the error: `Error: Invalid package.json` because the exploded folder name is **AndroidInAppBilling-master** not **AndroidInAppBilling**

If you wanna use the same command to make it work, then rename the exploded folder to `AndroidInAppBilling`.