# Invalid package.json in Custom cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to develop a custom plugin in cordova that give me location at every specified interval. Problem is that I don't have any **package.json** file in this plugin directory.

When I am trying to add this plugin into our cordova project i am getting **Invalid package.json** error.

Please help me I am new in cordova. What i have to do to resolve this error.

I am using this command to add the plugin in project

```
cordova plugin add ../loccation_plugin/LocationPlugin/
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had same issue while adding my custom plugin to project.
I am using plugman tool to create custom plugin and you may most probably be using plugman tool too.

If that is the case then execute following command to generate valid `package.json`:

```
plugman createpackagejson "path of your plugin"
```

This will ask you some basic question about plugin and will generate package.json file based on it.

Comment: please help me i am added in that directory but it showing error like "pkg is not defined",..,,

Comment: "pkg" is not defined

Comment: this was a bug in plugman cli which has been addressed recently. Please check following url:https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/597

Comment: If you are in the same directory then it become plugman createpackagejson .

Answer (score 5):

I meet the same 'pkg is not defined' problem, then I try to use `npm init` to create package.json file and succeed.

Comment: Tested and this works.  Go to the local directory of your plugin, run npm init with defaults, then return to your cordova directory and run "cordova plugin add <path to local directory with your plugin>"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but used this `npm init` instead, press Enter and fill in the data as asked on the cmd

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error.

Following the reasoning in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37699440/521197) I've realized that when we try to install a cordova plugin from a folder: **The name of target folder must be the same of plugin ID**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Windows while working on my custom plugin and it seems that the location of the plugin is the problem (Local Disk Location).

For example, the Cordova Project is located in `E:/projects/cordova-project` and i have a plugin in 2 different disks:

- custom-plugin-main:      `C:/plugins/myawesome-plugin-name`
- custom-secondary-plugin: `E:/plugins/myawesome-plugin-name`

Although the project and the plugin are located in the same Disk, If i install the plugin from the `E:` disk:

```
cordova plugin add E:/plugins/myawesome-plugin-name
```

The exception will be thrown, but if i install it from the C: disk:

```
cordova plugin add C:/plugins/myawesome-plugin-name
```

Then the plugin should be installed succesfully:

[image: Cordova Plugin Error: Invalid package.json]

Note that the plugins is the same but in different folders and disks ... **it's pretty weird, however that solved the problem for me.**

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after running this command in **cygwin**. My solution was to run the cordova command from **cmd**. As in other posts about this error, there is an issue with the path of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by generating a package.json file using the Plugman utility and I also had to move my plugin from a sub-directory within my Cordova project to the root directory of my Cordova project.

In other words, I moved the plugin from:

`my-cordova-project/extras/plugins`

to:

`my-cordova-project`

Answer (score 0):

Use **plugman** to install your plugin instead of **cordova**
for example my plugin is

```
hello-plugin
```

Now I am in the parent folder of hello-plugin

```
plugman install --platform android --project platforms/android --plugin ./hello-plugin
```

you can change android to other platforms that you want to install such as ios

if install successfully, you will find your plugin at

```
<project-name>\platforms\android\cordova\plugins
```

**To make it more clear**

I made a Batch file in Windows to make it clear about creating plugin to installing the plugin using **plugman**. You can copy the code below and put it in *anyname.bat* (and put it in your "project-folder/")
You can modify the code according to your needs. The code below, I fixed the command for Android only

```
@echo off
SET/P pluginName=Please input plugin name: 
call plugman create --name %pluginName% --plugin_id %pluginName% --plugin_version 1.0.0
call cd %pluginName%
call plugman platform add - -platform_name android
call plugman createpackagejson .
call cd ..
call plugman install --platform android --project platforms/android --plugin ./%pluginName%
```

reference
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/plugman.html